# How to dynamically fill out a form value field based on a link clicked on another page?

Tags: dynamic, email-contact-form

So I am brand new to ExpressionEngine....

I am on an expression engine entry page with a few hyperlinks...Based on which hyperlink I click, I want to navigate to another expression engine page with a contact form and dynamically set the value of the subject field based on which hyperlink was clicked on the previous page......How do I go about doing this?  FYI - I'm not new to web programming - other frameworks I've worked in let you set a parameter in the hyperlink so it becomes part of the web request to the next page where you can then grab the parameterized value for setting the subject.

If you could even point me in the right direction, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be a little more manual with expressionengine. You might have to set the parameters in the link yourself and use php (or a [plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/get-post-parameters))

Build the link similar to this:

```
<a href="/form?name={name}">{name}</a>
```

and fill out your form using php ([php must be enabled on the form template](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/php.html)):

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>">
```

Or that plugin:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{exp:parameters get="first"}">
```

Comment: I highly recommend using a plugin, as pure-PHP slows down your templates.

Comment: Thanks, Johnathan - this is the perfect solution for our low traffic site.

Comment: Thanks kgrote - I'll try looking into the plugin solution for the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Just use url segments. In the hyperlink href (www.domain.com/form) add whatever parameter you like to it (www.domain.com/form/subject) and then on the form page put value="{segment_2}"  in your input tag. 
Read more in the EE docs about segments. You might have to encode/decode the uri if you use spaces etc.

Comment: While you are technically correct (the best kind of correct), query strings would make more sense in this case than segments, as a segment would denote an entirely unique page. In this situation we just need to pass some metadata in order to modify an existing page.